# Retrieve specific fields from DB after authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Actually, I have this Method wich returns all fields of my table.

> ```
>     public ActionResult Index(string username, string searchString)
>     {
>
>         var UserLst = new List<string>();
>
>         var UserQry = from d in db.OrderDetails
>                        orderby d.Order.Username
>                        select d.Order.Username;
>         UserLst.AddRange(UserQry.Distinct());
>         ViewBag.username = new SelectList(UserLst);
>
>         var user = from m in db.OrderDetails
>                      select m;
>
>         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
>         {
>             user = user.Where(s => s.Order.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
>         }
>
>         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
>             return View(user);
>         else
>         {
>             return View(user.Where(x => x.Order.Username == username));
>         }
>     }
>
>
>
>     [HttpPost]
>     public string Index(FormCollection fc, string searchString)
>     {
>         return "<h3> From [HttpPost]SearchIndex: " + searchString + "</h3>";
>     }
> ```

My table looks like that :

Username---------Product----------Price----------N°Cart

test--------------Object1-------------20-----------110

test--------------Object2-------------84-----------110

cloud-------------Object2-------------84-----------541

Apple-------------Object8-------------65-----------874

What I want is, when my user is log on and when he's going to this page, he will see only rows with his username. In other words, I would like my method returns rows with the username of the logged in user.

Excuse me for my english, I wish you'll understand me. 
Thank you for your help, answers, links, I take all, I'm beginner in asp

Comment: Mapping a username field to a product doesn't seem right, shouldn't you be mapping roles instead? e.g. Admin/User etc.

Comment: Sorry, How can I set up this, returns rows where username=test when user test is log on ? I don't ask the solution but at least a "way of thinking" (I don't really know how to say it in english). Is that more clear ?

Comment: @Alternative - you shouldn't need to pass the username into the `Index` action, you can get the logged in user from the controller, there is a [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET Membership and joining on the Username field from your EF model  then just call User.Identity.Name. If so, then you can remove the parameter from the method:

```
  public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {

...
...

   return View(user.Where(x => x.Order.Username == User.Identity.Name));
```

Comment: it works, I was looking for something more complicated... Thank you all, and also be understanding with my english !